# What does "to pull a story" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I encountered this formulation, but I don't know what it means, and the online dictionary does not help me. So ...

What does "*pull a story*" mean?

Does it mean that some story is made up? Or rather the opposite, that something confidential is revealed?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's the context I'm looking for. You should make that an answer @StoneyB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a phrase from journalism, meaning *withdraw* the story from publication, as when a story in an early edition of a newspaper proves to be inaccurate or unfounded (or annoys a big advertiser) and is removed from subsequent editions.

Over the years the phrase has been extended to broadcast and internet journalism.